# How do I stop icons from blinking in Conky?

Tags: icons, conky, openbox

How I can stop blinking conky? I make in my config all what I want - transparent, showing icons above conky, but I cant do nothing with blinking! When I make `double_buffer yes` conky stop blinking, but I cant do nothing with icons that are under conky. 
I dont use conpiz and kde. I use openbox and Conky 1.8.1 . How I can fix blinking?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going into the `.conkyrc` configuation file and changing the line

```
own_window yes
```

I know I had that problem every time I opened and/or closed a file the Conky display would flicker/blink. When I changed the above from `no` to `yes` it worked like a charm.